# Add android assembleRelease dependency

Tags: android, gradle

I've tried almost everything from examples i've got from the internet to add a function/task to be executed before "assembleRelease" task, but none of them executed/run when i call `gradle assembleRelease`:

```
task preBuild1 << {
    println 'Copying correct build.gradle to the foo library'
    copy {
        from "../../androidRelated/gradle/foo"
        into "foo"
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        task.dependsOn preBuild1
    }
}
```

or:

```
dependencies {

    preBuild1

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'AudienceNetwork', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GoogleAIDL', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GooglePlay', ext:'aar')

...
```

those codes are on `build.gradle` file from a single android project. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. changing first one into:

```
task preBuild1(type: Exec) {
```

now it works '__')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you? I'm not 100% if I understand your question correctly.

```
afterEvaluate {
  assembleRelease.dependsOn {
    increment
  }
}

task increment() {
  doLast {
    println("increment ")
  }
}
```

Comment: too bad `Could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease' for root project 'gradleOut' of type org.gradle.api.Project`, same like when i add `assembleRelease.dependsOn preBuild1` directly at the end of the file.